# Binding callback to a templated object

Tags: c++, templates, boost-bind

I have a templated class that holds a callback, stored as a `std::function`

```
typedef std::function<void()> func_t;

template<typename T>
struct A
{
   T someMember;
   func_t callback;
};
```

This callback is called by some mechanism (boost::asio) and I want to pass arguments, so I bind them:

For example:

```
void a_callback( int v )
{
    std::cout << "value=" << v << "\n";
}
```

and I store it in the object that way.

```
enum EN { ONE, TWO };

int main()
{
    A<EN> a;

    a.callback = boost::bind( a_callback, 42); // ok
    a.callback(); // ok
}
```

So far, all good.

But now I want to pass the object itself to the callback function, so that it can do things on it. The callback becomes templated, as the object class is:

```
template<typename T>
void b_callback( A<T>& b, int v )
{
    std::cout << "value=" << v << "\n";
}
```

But attempting to bind it fails:

```
int main()
{
    A<EN> a2;  
    a2.callback = boost::bind( b_callback, a2, 42); 
}
```

Clang says:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'bind'
    a2.callback = boost::bind( b_callback, a2, 42); // build error
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1891:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'R'
    BOOST_BIND(F f, A1 a1, A2 a2)
/usr/local/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1868:20: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_BIND'
#define BOOST_BIND bind
```

[Full code here (coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6feee00c64a4c6c)

What did I do wrong ? How can I manage that ?

Comment: Try `b_callback<EN>` and you should get rid of bad habit of using UPPERCASE constants

Comment: @Slava 54 : Thanks for comment, but : `bad habit of using UPPERCASE constants`: why is that ? Any reference ? Or just personal habit ?

Comment: do you know where this habit came from? It is exactly what makes it bad habit.

Comment: @Slava ??? I don't get it, what do you mean ?

Comment: There is a good habit - use macros in UPPERCASE and non-macros not, because identifier conflict with preprocessor is a disaster. Then in C constants were defined as macros hence they were defined  in UPPEERCASE. Now using non macro constants the same way is a bad habit exactly for the same reason - it may conflict with preoprocessor. And conflict with preprocessor can be a disaster - best case you have compile error. Worst case endless debugging time. Got it now?

Comment: @Slava Ok, I got your point. And thats why modern C++ libraries now carefully design symbols so that the risk of name collision is very low (see `find /usr/include/boost  -name "*.hpp" -exec grep "\#define" {} \;` for example). So I understand the idea but your rationale seems a bit weak to me. Thanks anyway for the advice.

Comment: do you include only headers from modern C++ libraries? And those libraries do not include system headers? `find /usr/include/boost -name "*.hpp" -exec grep "\#define" {} \;` huh do the same for `/usr/include`. I did that for RH and found 121641 defines, good luck with that "low risk of collision"

Comment: @Slava 199059 over here. Again, I **see** your point, and I understand why you recommend that. But, except for the infamous windows.h, I never ran into such an issue. That thing even has mixed case symbols! So the problem isn't even about case, it's about badly designed symbols generally AND the whole preprocessor thing, that enables string replacements behind our back. So, yeah, for the situations I am dealing with, I'm ok with what I'm doing. Thanks for pointing this interesting topic out.

Comment: "So, yeah, for the situations I am dealing with, I'm ok with what I'm doing." right, but I had issue with that and irony that it was not my code. I had to use code from colleague that also was ok with what he was doing. And I had to deal with that crap, it was simply not his problem. He just wanted to use old habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a function template with a concrete type `EN`:

```
a2.callback = boost::bind(&b_callback<EN>, a2, 42);
```

as `b_callback` is a function template, not a function.

[**EXAMPLE**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6qGu6Y2AEDuBae9c)

Comment: Great, thanks. Always seems obvious once you got it in front, but I spend the whole afternoon on that! Templated C++ is hard...

Comment: @kebs the same happens to me some times :)